# I am in need of auto response email code in php,where the image specified must automatically delivered to the end user

Tags: php, html-email, auto-responder

This is my sample code for auto response email in php. When i try to send, the auto response they receiving is not the output. Rather, they are receiving the HTML code.

```
<?php
$to = 'test@gmail.com';
$subject = 'persona details';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$message = "
Customer Name: $name <br/>
Email Id: $email
   ";



  // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From:" . $email . "\r\n";


  // Auto response code

  $headers2 = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers2 .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
  $headers2 = "From:" . $to."\r\n";

  $body=<<<EMAIL
  <html>
   <head>
   <title>HTML email</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Sudhakar</h1>
  <p><img src='http://garciniainfotech.com/images/garcinia.jpg'> </p>
  </body>
  </html>

   EMAIL;

   mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
   mail($email,$subject,$body,$headers2);
   ?>
```